# Random meme help, randompuppy is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

It says "randompuppy" is not defined

And error at "}});"

So how do I define randompuppy?

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author == client.user){return}
  let message = msg.content.toLowerCase()
  if(message.startsWith (";meme") ) {
  async (client, message, args) => {
  const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
  const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)]
   const img = await randomPuppy(random);
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(`RANDOM`)
    .setFooter("test")
    .setImage(img)
    .setTitle(`Random Meme requested by <@${message.author.tag}>`)
    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`)
  msg.channel.send(embed);
  }});
```

Comment: Where have you defined `randompuppy`?

Comment: As Tyler said, you're getting an image url which the function named 'randomPuppy' is for. it uses a random subreddit like 'dankmeme', then a random post from dankmeme and from that post it copies the url of the post's image. You should make that asynchonous function for this to work

Comment: @Amineze it doesn't work, do I have to add something else?

Comment: @HiHiGetYEET091 I've added an answer, you can use it or use the answer linked by Assayag which does the same using an npm package

Answer (score 1):

There's an npm package as Assayag mentioned. RandomPuppy is a function that does a request to Reddit to get an image, you can do this on your on by using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const randomPuppy = async (random) => {
    //Perform a GET request
    const { data } = await axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${random}.json?limit=100`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })

    const { children } = data.data

    //Filter posts from those with no images
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(children.map(element => {
        const { url_overridden_by_dest } = element.data

        //Some posts doesn't include any image links
        if (url_overridden_by_dest != null || url_overridden_by_dest != undefined) {
            //Filter out empty links and those linked to a gallery
            if (url_overridden_by_dest.length > 0 && !url_overridden_by_dest.includes('gallery') && url_overridden_by_dest.includes('redd') && url_overridden_by_dest.includes('png')) {
                return url_overridden_by_dest
            }
        }
    }))

    //You can read more on Promises, we need an array from the results promise
    const images = []
    const failed = []

    for (const result of results) {
        if (result.status === 'rejected') {
            failed.push(result.reason)
            continue
        }
        if (result.value) {
            images.push(result.value)
        }
    }

    //Random image from the images links array
    const image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [random-puppy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-puppy) and fix the code:

```
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author == client.user) {
        return
    }
    let message = msg.content.toLowerCase()
    if (message.startsWith(";meme")) {
        async (client, message, args) => {
            const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
            const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)]
            const img = await randomPuppy(random);
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(`RANDOM`)
                .setFooter("test")
                .setImage(img)
                .setTitle(`Random Meme requested by <@${message.author.tag}>`)
                .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`)
            msg.channel.send(embed);
        }
    });
});
```